# Cordova-App HTML/JS Everything appears multiple times after leaving page and getting back

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, onsen-ui

I am working on a Cordova project using Onsen.
I have multiple ons-pages and if I change from one to another and back to the first one, the whole code is executed twice. If I do it again, everything happens three times, four times and so on.

Like I load a view with:

```
$(document).on('click','#next',function() {
    fn.load("views/test.html");
});
```

View looks like:

```
<ons-page id="test">
    <img class="back_icon" id="picture" src="pictures/graphic.png" alt="back"/>

    <script>
        console.log(1);
        $(document).on('click','#picture',function() {
            fn.load("views/back.html");
        });
    </script>
</ons-page>
```

I go to this page first time, console: 1
I go back to another view and use it again, console: 1, 1, 1
Again: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

And it does this with everything, but I have no clue why it does this. (It appears in Firefox, Chrome and on Android)

Has somebody had an idea for me? Seems like I am missing a basic point of switching between views...

Thank you!